# How to change QML ApplicationWindow Overlay size?

Tags: qt, popup, qml, overlay, applicationwindow

Since `Qt 5.10` it's possible setting up `Overlay` attached property for the `Popup` element. There is an example available here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html#modal-attached-prop . It's really useful for cases when there is a need for changing background for `Popup` having `dim:` property set to `true`. But there is no clue (at least for me) on how can I change `Overlay` size. For example, I have a custom `ApplicationWindow` overriding `contents:` property to be able drawing shadow over the window (my custom window doesn't have borders) and place `MouseArea` beyond borders to mimic the behavior of native windows. The sad part is - `Overlay` drawn over the entire window area that makes it ugly for the area beyond borders.

Does anyone knows a way to adjust overlay size (I mean background shadow at least) when using `dim:` property in `Popup`?

Here is a typical `Popup` code:

```
Popup {
        id: popupReleaseNotes
        x: Math.round(parent.width/2 - width/2)
        y: Math.round(parent.height/2 - height/2)
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
        modal: true
        dim: true
    }
```

Here you can see how it looks like in my app:

[image]

Overlay background goes over my custom boundaries, which means it's taking all the `ApplicationWindow` area. And this is what I'm trying to change. I didn't find any documented way so far.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I added a screenshot and `Popup` code. I won't add window element code cause it has nothing to do with the problem. I just implemented custom transparent borders to place `MouseArea` there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use ColorOverlay.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html

Anyway seems to me that you missed the Overlay.Modal. 
Reading the documentation(), I was expecting something like:

```
Popup {
        id: popupReleaseNotes
        x: Math.round(parent.width/2 - width/2)
        y: Math.round(parent.height/2 - height/2)
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
        modal: true

        visible: true

        Overlay.modal: Rectangle {
               anchors.fill: parent
               color: "#aacfdbe7"
        }
}
```

PS have a look to the Popup and its **Layout** in order to understand where it could be a problem of Content item vs Background. Maybe your dimming ha been done on the background that is bigger than the content.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I've tried it before posting a question. This `Rectangle` doesn't allow changing overlay area size.

Comment: Regarding the second thing (about `background` size). Yes, it's true. My custom window background equal to the window size. Is there anything I can do to `dim` on another item? Sadly, I have no idea how it could be done. Or lack of documenation.

Comment: Not even with anchors.fill, as I added? 
You should be able to change the size of the rectangle as you want.
Anyway, could you post the whole page? So could be easy to help you

Comment: No, it's not. Sadly, it still takes the whole window and can't be anchored to the other items.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts anyway. I guess I have to post it on Qt bugreports and ask for a possible solution (or confirmation about this behavior)